# Add array of filename as hyperlink in datatable jquery

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I have the following datatable:

```
     $('#myDt').DataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [{
            "defaultContent": "-",
            "targets": "_all"
        }],

        data: appArray,
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "name" },
            { "mData": "age" }
        ]
    } );
```

HTML:

```
<table id="myDt">   
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>MyPics</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Now my `appArray` array also contains a collection of files here is the structure:

```
[
{age: "29" ,files: {file1: 1505050304702, file2: 1505050304701}, name: "NewUser1"},
{age: "22" ,files: {file1: 1505050304731, file2: 1505050304739}, name: "NewUser2"}
]
```

I need to display the file names with a hyperlink in the above datatable  along with other data like name , age etc. All the files for a single record should be in the same cell. How can I do the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `render` callback. See [DataTable.js columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render)

As an example you could use:

```
render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
  return '<a href="'+row.files.file1+'">File 1</a>' +
    '<a href="'+row.files.file2+'">File 2</a>';
}
```